# Add a video file (any format) into a JButton

Tags: java, swing, video, jbutton, jmf

Is there any way to add a video (not `.gif` pictures) as a background for a `JButton`?  Or even for a `JLabel`?

I'm still a Java beginner so go easy on me please, I'm eager to learn :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java does not support video 'out of the box'.  It would require some extra API such as JMF.  Even then, it would take effort to shoehorn that video into the background of a `JComponent`.

Since you are a beginner, my advice is to start with (much) simpler tasks.

Comment: yes thanks for the quick answer! ill look into JMF and maybe ill get into more java courses to get better! Thanks again!